# Extracting NA data based on several conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have no idea of how to do this, so in that sense my question is a bit broad. My real dataset contains data from 100+ persons who had to fill out a questionnaire at 4 time points. Some of my data is missing and what I would like to know is: if the data is missing, is it missing for the whole questionnaire for that person at that time point? Or could it be that a person only 'failed' to answer 1 question or a few questions at the same time point?. `Question` in the dataset below goes from A to F (i.e. 6 questions).

Example code for which I want it to work:

```
ID <- rep(1:10, each = 24)
Question <- rep(LETTERS[1:6], 40)
Value <- round(runif(length(ID), 0, 5))
Time <- rep(c(0, 1, 3, 4), each = 6, times = 10)

df <- data.frame(ID, Question, Value, Time)
dfValue <- df[19:24, ]

df[19:24, ]$Value <- NA
df[28:30, ]$Value <- NA
df[49, ]$Value <- NA
df[55:61, ]$Value <- NA
```

As you can see, I created `NAs` for some `IDs` where for 2 occasions failed to fill out the entire questionnaire, on 1 occasion he/she failed to answer only 3 questions and on another someone failed to answer 1 question.

What I tried so far is:

```
missing <- df[which(is.na(df$Value)), ]
```

This works for a small data set like the one I gave (and with not too many `NAs`), but it gets tedious once you have a large dataset. Is there a way of achieving the same, but more convenient? My own dataset returns me a data frame with 569 observations. A bit much to go through on the eye.

For clarity: some algorithm / code that would check for every `ID` (or for every `Value == NA`) whether all other `Values` at the same `Time` are also `NA` or aren't. The idea is that it would return (based on example data above):

```
df[c(25:30, 49:54), ]

   ID Variable Value Time
25  2        A     1    0
26  2        B     4    0
27  2        C     3    0
28  2        D    NA    0
29  2        E    NA    0
30  2        F    NA    0
49  3        A    NA    0
50  3        B     2    0
51  3        C     2    0
52  3        D     2    0
53  3        E     2    0
54  3        F     3    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `dplyr` library in the following way:

```
library(dplyr)

df_summarized <-
df %>% 
 # Creating Answered variable to detect if there is an NA in Value variable
 mutate(Answered = !is.na(Value)) %>% 
 # Group by ID and Time
 group_by(ID, Time) %>%
 # Sum the number of Answered for ID and Time 
 summarise(Num_Ans = sum(Answered))
```

That returns a table like:

```
    ID   Time   Num_Ans
   <int> <dbl>   <int>
 1     1     0       6
 2     1     1       6
 3     1     3       6
 4     1     4       0
 5     2     0       3
 6     2     1       6
 7     2     3       6
 8     2     4       6
 9     3     0       5
10     3     1       0
....
```

So you may filter for the case there were no answers for the ID and time, i.e. Num_Ans = 0:

```
df_Sum %>% filter(Num_Ans == 0)

     ID  Time Num_Ans
  <int> <dbl>   <int>
1     1     4       0
2     3     1       0
```

And you may filter for the case where not all the answers were answered, i.e. Num_Ans < 6 and Num_Ans != 0:

```
df_Sum %>% 
 filter(Num_Ans < 6 & Num_Ans != 0)

    ID  Time Num_Ans
  <int> <dbl>   <int>
1     2     0       3
2     3     0       5
3     3     3       5
```

Comment: Detailed solution, thank you. Does this depend on the way the data is sorted?

Comment: @Anonymous No, that is because of the group_by function. It ties the values amoung the groups. I really recomend the `dplyr` library, one of the best for data analisys. The whole `tidyverse` is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tapply` to test `all(is.na(x))`, `x` being every chunk of `df$Value` split by `df$ID` and `df$Time`:

```
tapply(df$Value, list(df$ID, df$Time), function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

**EDIT** (see comment)

```
tapply(df$Value, list(df$ID, df$Time), function(x) sum(is.na(x)) %in% 1:5)
```

Comment: Smart to think of tapply. It however doesn't work entirely as I would hope. Is there a way to alter it so it would only return a value or `TRUE`  if the amount of NAs are >0 and <6 (since there are 6 questions) conditioned on `ID` and `Time`?

Comment: Something like `sum(is.na(x)) %in% 1:5`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the mighty data.table package.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# This will show in what time and ID, how many are missing
df[,missing := sum(is.na(Value)), .(Time,ID)]

# this will should all cases where the value is missing
df[missing != 0]

# next you can do simple aggregations to get answers like
# get cases where all values are missing
df[missing == 6]

#The second part of your question can be solved by subsetting this data.
#For example:
df[(ID == 1) & (is.na(Value))]
```

Comment: This seems to work exactly as I had hoped. Only the last line of code is not what I meant. I meant: `df [ missing < 6 & missing > 0 ] `. This returns only the missings that are > 0 and < 6, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just put the conditions in brackets. I'm afraid without bracket it might throw error. Try different combinations of values and you'll learn how output changes.

Comment: Just came to think of it: if I coerce a `data frame` into being a `data.table`, does that matter for other packages or other standard r usage? I for example use ggplot2 a lot

Comment: data.table is inherently a data.frame too. You can use it standard. Better to read this: http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf